# Counting member PER Active Directory Group using Powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, count

Good Morning World

I have written the below Powershell Script which gives me almost what I want.
The error is that this script gives me an incorrect value for the total of members (users).
The incorrect value of members is always 0 (zero).
I need to the number of members (users) PER group.

I welcome your help.

```
$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -filter 'Name -notlike "Domain Computers"' | select name -expandproperty name)
$Table = @()
$Record = [ordered]@{
    "Group Name" = ""
    "Name" = ""
    "Username" = ""
    "Membercount" = 0
            }
Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
    $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group | select name,samaccountname
    foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers)
    {
        $Record."Group Name" = $Group
        $Record."Name" = $Member.name
        $Record."UserName" = $Member.samaccountname
        $Record."Membercount" = $Membercount.count
        $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
        $Table += $objrecord
    }
}
$Table | export-csv C:\MB\GROUP-D.CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What  is `$Membercount.count` ? `$Membercount` is nowhere to be seen in your code

Comment: The incorrect value of members is always 0 (zero).

Comment: yes because you're using `$Membercount.count` instead of `$Arrayofmembers.Count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Arrayofmembers.Count is the correct parameter. Thanks to
Santiago Squarzon

Answer (score 0):

Correct,

You are using the below line of code to capture the count, but the Variable "$Membercount" has never been declared.

```
$Record."Membercount" = $Membercount.count
```

You set Arrayofmembers to fetch information for the group the loop is currently on.

```
$Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group | select name,samaccountname
```

Therefore, when the script runs, it will replace "$Group" with the group name. You can then use the below to get the actual count of members from the variable you created.

```
$Arrayofmembers.Count
```

The end result of the code will look as follows.

```
$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -filter 'Name -notlike "Domain Computers"' | select name -expandproperty name)
$Table = @()
$Record = [ordered]@{
    "Group Name" = ""
    "Name" = ""
    "Username" = ""
    "Membercount" = 0
            }
Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
    $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group | select name,samaccountname
    foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers)
    {
        $Record."Group Name" = $Group
        $Record."Name" = $Member.name
        $Record."UserName" = $Member.samaccountname
        $Record."Membercount" = $Arrayofmembers.count
        $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
        $Table += $objrecord
    }
}
$Table | export-csv C:\MB\GROUP-D.CSV -NoTypeInformation
```